# best way to split a char array with NUL terminators and delimiters?

Tags: c, string

I get as an input a char array in this format:    `"key = value\0key = value...\0"` (last pair is ended with 2 NUL terminators - one of the pair + one for the whole string)

and I want to split it into pairs of {key, value} in order to print them.

This is my approach, is there a better way to do so?

```
char str [] =   "line 1 = But I set fire to the rain\0line 2 = Watched it pour as I touched your face\0line 3 = Well, it burned while I cried\0line 4 = 'Cause I heard it screaming out your name, your name!\0";
char * p = str;
char key[10], value[128], * delimiter;

while(*p){
    memset(key,     0, sizeof(key));
    memset(value,   0, sizeof(value));

    delimiter = strchr(p, '=');
    strncpy(key, p, delimiter - p);
    // not sure where the NUL terminator is, so use strcpy
    strcpy(value, 1 + delimiter);

    printf("key: %s\n   value: %s\n", key, value);
    p += strlen(p) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Why make copies when you can just refer to the string itself?

Comment: This question may be more fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Because I'm saving the arrays for more processing

Comment: *Because I'm saving the arrays for more processing* That doesn't make any sense unless you're going to modify the copy and need the original later.

Comment: One hint: You use `strcpy()` and then `strlen()` to update the value of the pointer `p`. You could use a `while()` loop involving `p` to copy and advance the pointer.

Comment: @CIsForCookies. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options available to you, depending on whether you want `NUL`-terminated strings and whether your buffer is read-only or not.

If all you want to do is print the successive elements of  the combined string, you can use it as your buffer directly:

```
char str[] = ...;
char *key, *val;
for(key = str; *key; key += strlen(key) + 1) {
    val = strchr(key, '=') + 1;
    printf("%.*s = %s", val - key - 1, key, val);
}
```

Using `%.*s` tells `printf` to print a dynamic number of characters from the string.

If you want anything more advanced than that, you will probably use a two-pass approach. The first pass will count the number of key-value pairs, while the second will retain pointers, lengths, copies, or whatever other information you want. This approach will also require more cleanup than the original.

To get the number of pairs, you can do something like:

```
char str[] = ...;
char *p;
int count;
for(p = str, count = 0; *(p = strchr(p, '\0') + 1); count++) ;
```

If you are OK with having pointers to the key and value in the original buffers (along with the length of the key), you only need to allocate `count` pairs of pointers and lengths:

```
char *keys, *vals;
int i, *klens;

keys = malloc(count * sizeof(char *));
vals = malloc(count * sizeof(char *));
klens = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
if(keys == NULL || vals == NULL || klens == NULL) {
    goto cleanup;
}

for(i = 0, p = str; i < count; i++) {
    keys[i] = p;
    vals[i] = strchr(p, '=') + 2;
    klens[i] = vals[i] - keys[i] - 3;
    p = strchr(vals[i], '\0') + 1;
}

// Use the data, e.g., to print:
for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("%.*s = %s\n", klens[i], keys[i], vals[i]);
}

cleanup:
if(keys != NULL) free(keys);
if(vals != NULL) free(vals);
if(klens != NULL) free(klens);
```

If you want to have a writable version of each key and value, you have two options:

1. Allocate the buffers for each one, and use `strcpy` to copy each key and value individually. In this case, the cleanup will be a bit more complicated because you will have to set all the elements of `keys` and `vals` to `NULL` in the beginning (e.g. with `memset`), and deallocate all of the non-`NULL` elements after you are done.
2. A more efficient option might be to just copy the entirety of `str` into a newly allocated writable buffer, and just replace `=` with `\0`. You would be able to do this at the same time that you compute `keys` and `vals`. Cleanup would not be any more complicated than before. You would just have to free the additional text buffer.

Comment: OP has mentioned that he is using arrays because he needs them for further processing.

Comment: @machine_1, I'll add a note for that in a bit.